# How to get Global payment GP API accesstoken?

Tags: realex-payments-api, global-payments-api

I have enabled the GP API in the global payment sandbox and now I am testing its API through the postman tool.

So as per the GP API document, we need to generate the token using the below information
https://developer.globalpay.com/api/access-token#/Create%20token/post_accesstoken

And 
I am receiving, the below error,

[image]

Comment: Could you please post an example of your code? Please obfuscate the app_id, nonce and secret.